# Add code coverage to Jasmine testing in browser

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, istanbul

I use code coverage with npm and grunt locally, but I want to demonstrate this **in browser**.

If I open a codepen how can I have code coverage generated in browser?
Please show an example of this.

Here I'm testing a controller and Jasmine tests the code but I would like to know if it's 100% covered and show that **in browser**.
http://codepen.io/clouddueling/pen/Jwaru?editors=001

Could I submit my code to a server?  Have it tested instantly elsewhere like on heroku and get the results?
Can Instanbul run in the client somehow and output an html report or json string?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Blanket.js](http://blanketjs.org/), which support jasmine test runner, to run a code coverage in the browser itself.

Here is a [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/uQwec6vVHOyviO3C9ts7?p=preview) demonstrating your sample app and specs. Few key points to note here are:

```
<!-- Use of data-cover provided by blanket to test coverage of concerned file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js" data-cover></script>
```

Blanket js needs an [adapter for jasmine](https://github.com/alex-seville/blanket/blob/master/docs/intermediate_browser.md). [**jasmine-blanket.js**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alex-seville/blanket/master/src/adapters/jasmine-blanket.js) is the adapter shown in the plunker.

I preferred plunker over codepen. Hope that helps. Isn't this slick?

**update 9-11-2017** blanket.js project is not actively maintained, you can see on their github repository.
[image]

Comment: I have to wait 40 minutes for the bounty but that is freaking slick!  If I remove one of the tests it highlights the red code xD

Comment: Glad it was helpful. We use Istanbul, but this is a light weight library which I think can be used full fledged when I think of training on TDD and code coverage (setting up your example) within the browser by totally abstracting any server side related configuration. @MichaelCalkins

Comment: I have been trying for a day and a half to figure out how to code coverage into some example jasmine tests I had on plunker and this is exactly what I was missing. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

If you need coverage and complexity data I highly suggest that you look into Grunt.io and NPM.  NPM has packages like karma-coverage that will give you a full coverage report of your application.  Grunt is your automated task runner for these reports.  But remember that 100% coverage is not always relevant.  This is where a tool for code complexity comes in.  I use the NPM package grunt-complexity along with karma-coverage to see what is not covered and then to determine how much value full test coverage is in that part of my code.

Eghead has a nice grunt intro video https://egghead.io/lessons/gruntjs-introduction-to-grunt.

Hope this helps a bit,

Jordan

Comment: I already use grunt and npm locally, but I wanted to do it in the browser for teaching examples.

Comment: I the karma-coverage can be configure to output to html.  It pretty slick too.  I think Vojta from Angular worked on it.

Comment: I basically want to run instanbul in the browser, look at my codepen, using that can I do code coverage?

Comment: You can run a result of a Instabul report in the browser(since it outputs html), i just dont think you can run your test and magically get instanbul to render your coverage in a browser without a server.